# Unsigned int overflow

Tags: c

I am facing an unsigned integer over flow issue 
i.e `unsigned int x= < max value * max value >` 
when I print x it is giving me the -ve value even though it is of unsigned integer

I am eager to understands how the compiler is making that as a negative vale

how do I over come this problem ??

thank you in advance

Comment: **Where** is [your minimal example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's probably because you're printing it as a signed integer. This is why we need a minimal example - the error is probably not where you seem to think it is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It helps enormously if we don't have to guess what code you've written. Please see how to create an MCTRE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Since I have to guess, I expect you are using `printf("u = %d\n", u);` instead of the correct `printf("u = %u\n", u);`, but it has to be a guess since you've not given us very much information to work on at all.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler itself is not treating it as a signed value, that's almost certainly because you're using the `%d` format string for outputting it.

Use the `%u` one for unsigned decimal values and you see it have the "right" value (right in terms of signedness, not right in terms of magnitude, which will be wrong because you've performed an operation leading to overflow).

Answer (score 0):

How are you printing it? Probably using `printf`. `printf` prints your unsigned ints as if they were signed (at least if you use %d). But this doesn't change the fact that the number is unsigned and hence positive.

Here's how you can check it: compare it to 0 and see what happens. So add this right after your `printf`:

```
if (x>=0) printf("positive\n");
else printf("negative\n");
```

and see what happens.

Comment: let me tell u the scenario , I have an device which I am running for more then 10 days and I have counter which is unsigned int which counts the number of bytes that is coming but after ten day I am seeing some negative , I know it is getting overflowed but even though if it is getting overflowed it should print negative number right

Comment: @Rajiv - if you'll read my answer, you'll see that the print writes negative even it it's positive, because the print thinks it's signed even if it's unsigned. So it prints negative but in reality it's positive. The reason is you use `printf("%d")` to print. Try instead to use `printf("%u")` so it knows it's unsigned.